# "TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found" when I try to attach an encrypted image for mailing using python

Tags: python, encryption

I am encrypting an image which I want to share through the application. When I try to send it(attached in an email), it raises an error which I am failing to understand!
Below is the code to encrypt the image(to be run once, when re-run, it decrypts)

```
image_path = "<image_path>.jpg"
key = <integer less than 256>

with open(image_path,'rb') as im:
    image_data = im.read()
print(type(image_data))

image_byte = bytearray(image_data)
print(type(image_byte))

for index, value in enumerate(image_byte):
    image_byte[index] = value^key

# open image for writing
with open(image_path,'wb') as wm:
    wm.write(image_byte)
print("Encryption succesful.")
```

The code I am using to attach the encrypted image is below. It works fine with an image that is not encrypted.

```
import smtplib
import imghdr
from email.message import EmailMessage

image = "<image_name>.jpg"
Sender_Email = "****@gmail.com"
Reciever_Email = "****@gmail.com"
Password = "****"

newMessage = EmailMessage()                         
newMessage['Subject'] = "Encrypted Image" 
newMessage['From'] = Sender_Email                   
newMessage['To'] = Reciever_Email 

message_content = '''Please find the attached image for decryption.
Use the approriate software to be able to decrypt.
Kind regards.

'''
newMessage.set_content(message_content) 

# open image for reading
with open(image, 'rb') as f:
    image_data = f.read()
    image_type = imghdr.what(f.name)
    image_name = f.name


newMessage.add_attachment(image_data, maintype='image', subtype=image_type, filename=image_name)

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    
    smtp.login(Sender_Email, Password)              
    smtp.send_message(newMessage)
print("message sent")
```

When I run the code and the image is encrypted, it raises the error below

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-214-7773731cfdc5> in <module>
     29 
     30 
---> 31 newMessage.add_attachment(image_data, maintype='image', subtype=image_type, filename=image_name)
     32 
     33 with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:

~\anaconda3\lib\email\message.py in add_attachment(self, *args, **kw)
   1154 
   1155     def add_attachment(self, *args, **kw):
-> 1156         self._add_multipart('mixed', *args, _disp='attachment', **kw)
   1157 
   1158     def clear(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\email\message.py in _add_multipart(self, _subtype, _disp, *args, **kw)
   1142             getattr(self, 'make_' + _subtype)()
   1143         part = type(self)(policy=self.policy)
-> 1144         part.set_content(*args, **kw)
   1145         if _disp and 'content-disposition' not in part:
   1146             part['Content-Disposition'] = _disp

~\anaconda3\lib\email\message.py in set_content(self, *args, **kw)
   1169 
   1170     def set_content(self, *args, **kw):
-> 1171         super().set_content(*args, **kw)
   1172         if 'MIME-Version' not in self:
   1173             self['MIME-Version'] = '1.0'

~\anaconda3\lib\email\message.py in set_content(self, content_manager, *args, **kw)
   1099         if content_manager is None:
   1100             content_manager = self.policy.content_manager
-> 1101         content_manager.set_content(self, *args, **kw)
   1102 
   1103     def _make_multipart(self, subtype, disallowed_subtypes, boundary):

~\anaconda3\lib\email\contentmanager.py in set_content(self, msg, obj, *args, **kw)
     35         handler = self._find_set_handler(msg, obj)
     36         msg.clear_content()
---> 37         handler(msg, obj, *args, **kw)
     38 
     39     def _find_set_handler(self, msg, obj):

~\anaconda3\lib\email\contentmanager.py in set_bytes_content(msg, data, maintype, subtype, cte, disposition, filename, cid, params, headers)
    229                      disposition=None, filename=None, cid=None,
    230                      params=None, headers=None):
--> 231     _prepare_set(msg, maintype, subtype, headers)
    232     if cte == 'base64':
    233         data = _encode_base64(data, max_line_length=msg.policy.max_line_length)

~\anaconda3\lib\email\contentmanager.py in _prepare_set(msg, maintype, subtype, headers)
     94 
     95 def _prepare_set(msg, maintype, subtype, headers):
---> 96     msg['Content-Type'] = '/'.join((maintype, subtype))
     97     if headers:
     98         if not hasattr(headers[0], 'name'):

TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

advise please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This line msg['Content-Type'] = '/'.join((maintype, subtype)) is the Problem and it means at least one oft the 2 values you want to join are not strings but None

Comment: You are scrambling the byte data in the image file, so `imghdr` can no longer determine what type of image it is, so `image_type` will be `None`.